# How to change the image source in kivy?

Tags: python, image, kivy

I am trying to make an app that shows one image. When I click in some button, the function will change the source of this image, therefore this image will change. So, I tried only change the line image.source, I think the correct way to do this is using a stringproperty, but I also have not had success with it. So, my code is:
.py

```
class PrimeiroScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'um'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        fonte = StringProperty('cafe.jpg')

    def fc1(self):
        self.ids.image.source = (fonte)
        self.ids.image.fonte = "cafe.jpg"
        #self.ids.image.source = "cafe.jpg"


class MyImage(Image):
    fonte = StringProperty()

class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

and .kv:

```
<RootScreen>:
    PrimeiroScreen:

<PrimeiroScreen>:
    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'tb-rl'
        ScrollView:
            #size: 100, 100
            #pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 10, 10
                spacing: 5, 5
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size_hint_y:  None
                width: 500
                height: self.minimum_height
                Button:
                    text: "1"
                    #color: 0,0,0,1
                    font_size: '20dp'
                    size: (200, 40)
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    on_release: root.fc1()
    AnchorLayout:
    Image:
        source:'logo.jpg'
        id: image
```

I am learning about AnchorLayout, and StackLayout, so it's not working.
Very thanks everyone, for awser my newbie question. Nice weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is with your current code there is no `fonte` defined(at least for me with copy&paste), you need to use `self.fonte`.

But anyway, you should access the `source` directly, otherwise you'd need to make another function that handles your property updating and doing something when it changes i.e. passing it to `source`, which already is a `StringProperty`, therefore you'd go really around the solution until you reached it.

```
<RootScreen>:
    PrimeiroScreen:

<PrimeiroScreen>:
    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'tb-rl'
        ScrollView:
            #size: 100, 100
            #pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 10, 10
                spacing: 5, 5
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size_hint_y:  None
                width: 500
                height: self.minimum_height
                Button:
                    text: "1"
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                    font_size: '20dp'
                    size: (200, 40)
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    on_release: image.source='newcafe.png'
    MyImage:
        source: 'cafe.jpg'
        id: image
```

Comment: You don't need to write `root.ids.image`, `image` alone should be sufficient.